# Minimum of Timestamp BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I get the following error when running this simple query in Bigquery with standard SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(created) as mm FROM `projectId.ds.User`
```

Column created has type cloud.helix.Timestamp, which differs from the expected type of INT64 Dismiss
COMPOSE QUERY

The created field has datatype Timestamp, is nullable, but contains no null values.

This query works however in Legacy SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(created) as mm FROM [projectId:ds.User]
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you using the same timestamp data type for both? If DT string was used in legacy to store pre-1970 dates, then using Unix now will throw an error...

Comment: The tables are the same. In fact there is only one table called User but different syntax to access it. With BigQuery you set a flag 'Use Legacy SQL' to switch your query syntax. The exact same TIMESTAMP datatype is being used (as far as I can tell as a user).

Comment: What is even more spooky is that I can run that Modern SQL query on with no error another one of my tables, which has the same created field with datatype TIMESTAMP and nullable.

Comment: Have you tried `select min(cast(created as Date)) as mm`? If that one falls over, might be a piece of duff data

Comment: It gives the same error. And even if I do SELECT cast(created as Date) I get the same error.

Comment: Looks like there's some data in that field that's causing an issue.

Comment: Something is generating a legacy timestamp representation that the standard SQL engine doesn't expect to see. You may want to star [the issue on the public tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=841) for updates and I will also try to follow up here when I know more.

Comment: If you can provide a set of job ids that are affected, we can prioritize a fix for those tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix has been rolled out by Google addressing this error.
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=841